# How to write a template to automatically write "server.x=hostname:Quorom_Port:Election_Port" in zoo.cfg

Tags: apache-zookeeper, chef-recipe, chef-template

I want "server.x=hostname:Quorom_Port:Election_Port" value to be be written to zoo.cfg using a template based on number hosts declared in attributes/default.rb file

```
default['zookeeper']['servers'] = ["hostname1", "hostname2", "hostname3"]
default['zookeeper']['follower_port'] = 2888
default['zookeeper']['election_port'] = 3888
```

For the above attributes, the following values should be automatically written in zoo.cfg file using a template:

```
server.1= hostname1:2888:3888
server.2= hostname2:2888:3888
server.3= hostname3:2888:3888
```

Please let me know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%- if node['zookeeper']['servers'] %>
    <%- node['zookeeper']['servers'].each_with_index do |host, idx| %>
        server.<%= idx+1 %>=<%= host %>:<%= node['zookeeper']['follower_port']%>:<%= node['zookeeper']['election_port']%>
    <%- end %>
<%- end %>
```

The above piece of code solved the problem.